# JQuery select menu returning error Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML:

```
<form action="#">
    <fieldset>
        <label>Escolha:</label>
        <select id="horizonte">
            <option value=1>1 Mês</option>
            <option value=2>2 Meses</option>
            <option value=3 selected="selected">3 Meses</option>
            <option value=6>6 Meses</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $("#horizonte").selectmenu();
});
```

Why is the select menu not being initialized correctly?

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z69ouswy/)

Comment: `.selectmenu()` seems to be from a plugin that's not included in your fiddle. It's not a native jQuery function.

Comment: what is selectmenu()? are you using a plugin?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the 1st example as per http://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/

Comment: He has jquery UI checked, but I never used it before so not sure what's going

Comment: I'm using JQuery and JQuery UI

Comment: in the jsfiddle am getting $("#horizonte") is null probably null. will be undefined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Selectmenu widget wasn't added till version 1.11 as the [API Documentation lists](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/)

> version added: 1.11

Include jQuery UI of at least version 1.11

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#horizonte").selectmenu();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<form action="#">
  <fieldset>
    <label>Escolha:</label>
    <select id="horizonte">
      <option value=1>1 Mês</option>
      <option value=2>2 Meses</option>
      <option value=3 selected="selected">3 Meses</option>
      <option value=6>6 Meses</option>
    </select>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: You beat me to it.  Here's a fiddle I was working on using the jQuery UI CDN for 1.11:  http://jsfiddle.net/edwardcoyle86/z69ouswy/4/